# GridControl showing no data but empty rows C#

Tags: c#, datatable, devexpress, datarow, gridcontrol

I have a gridcontrol which needs to be populated with some data.

I have created a datatable and populated data in  datarow and added to the table. Data is present in **table** on analysis. Datatable is then set as datasource for grid.
Code is below.

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Tran Date");
        table.Columns.Add("Due Date");
        table.Columns.Add("Voucher");
        table.Columns.Add("Vr No");
        table.Columns.Add("Bill Amount");
        table.Columns.Add("OutStanding");
        table.Columns.Add("Remittance");
        table.Columns.Add("Balance");
        

        for (intcount=0;intcount<=BackupFunctions.mdtAgeingTemp.Rows.Count - 1;intcount++)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            row["Tran Date"] = BackupFunctions.mdtAgeingTemp.Rows[intcount][1];
            row["Due Date"] = BackupFunctions.mdtAgeingTemp.Rows[intcount][2];
            row["Voucher"]= BackupFunctions.mdtAgeingTemp.Rows[intcount][3];
            row["Vr No"] = BackupFunctions.mdtAgeingTemp.Rows[intcount][4];
            row["Bill Amount"] = BackupFunctions.mdtAgeingTemp.Rows[intcount][10];
            row["OutStanding"] = BackupFunctions.mdtAgeingTemp.Rows[intcount][5];
            row["Remittance"] = BackupFunctions.mdtAgeingTemp.Rows[intcount][6];
            row["Balance"] = BackupFunctions.mdtAgeingTemp.Rows[intcount][7];

            table.Rows.Add(row);
            
        }
        grdAgeing.DataSource = table;
```

Its found that 5 rows which is the result is displaying but they are empty. Could you figure out the issue in my code.

Comment: Can you post the grid code? The code used to make the grid.

Comment: Are you asking designer code. Do you need the entire code of grid in designer

Comment: Issue got solved.Thanks.

Comment: Check the field names in your grid. They must be the same as the names of columns in DataTable.

Comment: I have given summary to be displayed in grid for a column balance and summarytype  was given sum. But its not displaying. I have fixed the above issue using gridView1.populateColumns() method. Before that summary was displaying. But if populateColumns is removed data will not be displayed in grid. Also when rightclicked context menu will appear. In that sum and average are greyed out and none is selected. I have done all deisgntime settings. Still it is not displaying. Please help.

Comment: Issue got fixed. There was a space in the fieldname